# How to align X-Axis ticks on vertical gridlines (Chart.js, Bar-Chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, alignment

I would like to align the X-axis label exactly on the vertical gridlines and not in between. In a line chart this is active by default.

Is the align option not applicable for bar charts? [common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) Or am I doing something wrong?

```
    var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        x: {
          ticks: {
            align: 'start'
        },
        }
      },
      events: []
    }
  }
```

[My example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Syncd/8z6rm9ck/5/)

What i want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by setting the labelOffset dynamically through an ChartJs-API call.

```
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);    
const visibleMetas = myChart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
let offset = visibleMetas[0].data[0].width / 2
myChart.options.scales.x.ticks.labelOffset = -offset;
myChart.update();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Syncd/8z6rm9ck/

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I set `offset` to `false`.

```
new Chart(chartRef.nativeElement, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: { datasets: datasets }
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          offset: false // here
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```